# How to install third party library Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, git, swift2, xcode7, cocoapods

I installed this [library](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss.git) in my project (a command line tool) via Cocoapods, but, even perfectly following all the instructions, Xcode doesn't see the module even if it's in the same workspace of my program

This is my Podfile:

```
platform :osx, '10.11.5'
use_frameworks!

target 'my_program' do

    #no version required, otherwise it throws an error
    pod 'Gloss',  :git => 'https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss.git'

end
```

and, as said, it installs the library without any error and creates a 'my_program.xcworkspace', which is where I should build the program instead of 'my_program.xcodeproj'. The problem is that I can't import the library in the main source file because Xcode thinks that there is no module named 'Gloss' in the workspace (even if there actually is).

What could I do?
Thanks

**EDIT**

I discovered that command line tools don't support framework. Thanks, Apple.
Anyway, I won't delete the question so that someone having my same struggle can have a quick answer

Answer (score 1):

Did you build after importing Gloss?

xCode gave me an error saying there was 'no such module' until i built the project and it then detected it.

Comment: Yeah,I tried, but it still doesn't work. Most of the times it doesn't even build or, when it does, it crashes and gives a run-time error saying that the image of the module wasn't found.
I'll try again anyway

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried it for platform ios rather than osx. I don't know enough to  say if it could be the difference in platform or not but that seems to be the only difference from what i can see.